# retaining checkbox and POP Up to add more

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have made a form in which a person puts up his details.
 After completing the form and submitting it, I want a popup which should ask "Do you want to add more?","Yes or No ?".
If Yes is chosen, the some values filled in the form should be retained and the rest should appear blank.
On NO the page should get freshened with everything blank.
I am able to retain the values of the drop down items and text fields,but I am not able to retain the values of the check box items.
My check box code :

```
  <label>Hotel Facilities</label>
    </td><td class="row1"> :</td>                                                           <td class="row1" width="70%">
    <div style=" font-weight:normal; color: #4B4B4B;font-size: 12px; width:260px; background:#D2D2D2; max-height:300px; overflow:scroll;overflow-x:hidden;">
<?php $dcs=mysql_query("select * from `tblfacility` where `Type`='Rm'");
                   while($dc=mysql_fetch_array($dcs)){?>
                             <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="<?php echo $dc['FId']; ?>">
<?php echo $dc['Facility'];?> <br />

                    <?php  }?>
                    </div>
```

I tried to retain by using:

```
<input name="check_list[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $dc['FId']; ?>" <?php if(isset($_POST['check_list[]'])) echo "checked='checked'"; else echo $dc['Facility']; ?>
```

but it did not worked

Please help me how to retain its values after submitting that page.

And the pop up I am at present using is just an alert message and hence it just have OK button:

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        echo "<script>alert ('Do You want to Add More ?');</script>";
    $HId=$_POST['HId'];
    ?>
```

hence it is just showing OK button after submitting .
Please guide how to put Yes or No button after submitting hence is Yes some values will be retained and if NO the whole from will be refreshed.

Comment: Isn't `confirm('Do You want to Add More ?')` what you're looking for?

Comment: this will be a common for to add student's details, hence if I am adding the details of all the student of batch, hence the batch details will remain same for everyone, therefore after details of one candidate is submitted I want a pop up DO YOU WANT TO ADD MORE ?
YES or NO ?; If Yes those batch details will be retained from the earlier added and only some fields will be empty.

My present pop up is just an alrt mssg and hence it is not giving me option to put YES or NO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `checked='checked'` just use `"selected"` or `"selected=true"`. I hope it works!

Comment: Actually, the value doesn't make any difference, so long as the attribute is actually defined.

Comment: Agree, if the attribute "selected" is mentioned, its enough. But I'm curious as to why it didnt work for our friend here. :(